# Quirky behavior of Series[]

Tags: series-expansion

This is a "what's going on?" question about MMa behavior, not so much a "how to fix?"

This code calculates a Taylor series for a two-term Gaussian Mixture:

```
gau[x_, v_] := (1/Sqrt[2*Pi*v])*E^-((x^2)/(2*v));
f[x] := gau[x + m, B]/2 + gau[x - m, B]/2;
n = 9;
Series[Log[f[x]], {x, 0, n}]
```

$$
 \log \left(\frac{e^{-\frac{m^2}{2 B}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sqrt{B}}\right)-\frac{x^2\left(B-m^2\right)}{2 B^2}-\frac{m^4 x^4}{12 B^4}+\frac{m^6 x^6}{45 B^6}-\frac{17 m^8 x^8}{2520 B^8}+O\left(x^{10}\right)  
  $$

But if I change n from 9 to 10, I get a trainwreck of unreadable output.  The puzzling part is that even the x^4 term is messed up for n=10 when it was fine for n=9.  This suggests that something is wrong internally with how Series simplifies the derivatives its calculating.

It's no problem to fake up a Series[]-esque function that can handle the higher derivatives:

```
Sum[(D[Log[f[x]], {x, j}] /. x -> 0 // Together)*(x^j)/(j!), {j, 0, 16}] // PowerExpand
```

$$
-\frac{929569 m^{16} x^{16}}{10216206000 B^{16}}+\frac{10922 m^{14} x^{14}}{42567525
   B^{14}}-\frac{691 m^{12} x^{12}}{935550 B^{12}}+\frac{31 m^{10} x^{10}}{14175
   B^{10}}-\frac{17 m^8 x^8}{2520 B^8}+\frac{m^6 x^6}{45 B^6}-\frac{m^4 x^4}{12 B^4}+\frac{x^2
   \left(m^2-B\right)}{2 B^2}-\frac{m^2}{2 B}-\frac{\log (B)}{2}+\frac{1}{2} (-\log (2)-\log
   (\pi ))
  $$

To make this work, I had to put either Together or Simplify in there, but it worked.  So what's going wrong internally with Series[]?  Is this a bug?

Comment: I can confirm the trainwreck with n=10, but it goes away if I do `FullSimplify@Series[Log[f[x]],{x,0,n}].`

Comment: Might be some internal heuristics about when/how to simplify intermediate expressions. There's a balance between giving an awkward result from undersimplification, and hanging from trying to hard to simplify.

Comment: I confirm that. I also tried to use `Trace` with `TraceInternal->True` on both series, all the internal steps seems to be the same, no specific reason for that ...
The problem seems to be coming from `System\`Private\`InternalSeries` ...

Comment: There are lots of calls to `Integrate` in the series however ....